# Proper way to enforce that another developer does not define a method that may be used to break encapsulation?

Tags: php, oop, interface

I have been writing up a new Account class at work and there are some methods that I have intentionally left out because I worry that implementing them would cause certain types of boolean logic to not be encapsulated by the class.

For example, imagine our Account class has a `billing_option` property that is used to define how an account would like to pay for future orders, either `INVOICED` or `CREDIT_CARD`:

```
class Account {

    const INVOICED    = 'INVOICED';
    const CREDIT_CARD = 'CREDIT_CARD';

    /**
     * List of acceptable billing options.
     * @var array
     */
    private static $BILLING_OPTIONS = [
        self::INVOICED,
        self::CREDIT_CARD
    ];

    protected $billing_option;

    public function setBillingOption($billing_option)
    {
        if (!in_array($billing_option, self::$BILLING_OPTIONS)) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid billing option provided");
        }

        $this->billing_option = $billing_option;
    }
}
```

For this class, I have intentionally left out the getter method, `getBillingOption`, because I want the logic to be confined to single area in the app.

Basically I am trying to avoid this:

```
// Check if we can bill an account by invoicing them
if ($account->getBillingOption() == "INVOICED") {
    // do stuff
}
```

Why? Well what if we decided that only members that have been with us 3 years or longer can choose to be `INVOICED` and everyone else must use a credit card at time of purchase? Now you have to update everywhere this logic is being performed.

But if I encapsulate this to:

```
// Check if we can bill an account by invoicing them
if ($account->canPayByInvoice()) {
    // do stuff
}
```

All I have to do is define a method `canPayByInvoice()`, which can determine the logical value internally within the account object, so now I only have to update it one place:

```
class Account {

    ...

    public function canPayByInvoice()
    {
        $is_old_enough = /* today - created_at > 3 years */;

        return $is_old_enough && $this->billing_option == self::INVOICED;
    }

    ...
}
```

So, in order to try and prevent other developers in the company from defining a `getBillingOption()` method, I perform a `method_exists` check and throw an exception if someone tried to define it, like so:

```
class Account {

    ...

    public function __construct()
    {
        if (method_exists($this, 'getBillingOption')) {
            throw new Exception(
                'Do not use getBillingOption to determine the billing option. Use canPayByInvoice() or canPayByCreditCard() instead.'
            );
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Although this kind pushes my point from within the code, I feel it's a bit hacky, and I was wondering: What is the most acceptable way to enforce that a method **cannot** get defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious thing that can be done to get around your scenario, is to just name the method something different than what you expect.  There is no substitution for standards, code reviews, or docblocks for this type of thing in my opinion.

There is a however the [final](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php) keyword, so what you could do is write the getter and have it throw an exception.  You make the getter final in your class, and that would prevent anyone from changing it in a subclass.

Comment: I am gonna give this a shot. I like this recommendation because it will unclutter the constructor and place emphasis on the methods I don't want to be used throughout the app.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately there is no *technical* solution to this. Writing proactively defensive code like your `method_exists` in the constructor is madness. The developer who is about to implement that getter will either delete that check, or name the method `reallyGetBillingOption`, or one of the other infinite possibilities they could name it.

You cannot defend against bad coders with code. At least not with this kind of code. You *could* install a style checker in your repository which enforces certain constraints on the code whenever anybody checks something in. But again, "`reallyReallyGetBillingOption`"…

Ultimately you need to solve this by **educating** your fellow developers. Communicate. Peer review. Document. Explain. Quality control. Tell them why and why not to write code a certain way. The only way to prevent bad code from being written is by not having people that write bad code work on your codebase.

Comment: I am entirely on board with your mindset. I think this has been the biggest issue that I have encountered at my place of work with the other developers. And you are absolutely right, they will just go ahead and define `reallyGetBillingOption`, and I have no control over it when I find it 3 months later and they have already called it in 12 different places and it irritates me that I feel I would need to program *defensively* to mitigate this. The struggle is real.

Comment: The better way to handle it is to push Peer/Code review.  This is a big reason for Github, Bitbuckett pull requests or a tool like Atlassian Crucible.